# how to Create my own shortcut key as Ctrl Alt Del

Tags: windows, vbscript, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I need to create my own shortcut key, as in when we press **Ctrl + Alt + Delete** we get the task manager, likewise i need to click some other 2 keys to execute my program.
How should i do this ?

and also i need to know what language i need to program this?

I am using Windows Vista as my OS.

Answer (score 1):

I think what he means is he wants to be able to create shortcut keys in his application.

If you're using Visual Studio, you can do this through the visual designer in menu options.

Anyways, I hope this article sheds some light onto the situation:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839201

You tagged vb, and this article explains it in VB as well as C#.

Good luck.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure the OP wants to create a keyboard shortcut that the Windows *operating system* (not an application) will understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use a [hotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) under AutoHotKey to [run](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) another program.  Once you have an autohotkey script running, you can also add keys to perform actions within that program, set up other keys to launch other programs, etc.  See entries under StackOverflow's 'autohotkey' tag and other help pages referred to from those links.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut that performs the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> action for you
(very useful in environments where OSK is not accessible). Create a shortcut to the following:
`C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:::{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}`

Double-click that shortcut to access the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> screen. Now you can forget about the inception through multiple RDP.